# How to draw multiple graphs with the same axes and is it even possible to do it in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to build a graph similar to the following but with my data.
[image: [1 in the comments]]
It turns out there is a common axis between two adjacent quarters. And each axis has its own dimension.
The best thing I got was the following drawing.
[image: [2 in the comments]]
My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines as axislines
%matplotlib widget
#Data
u01 = np.array([0.00, 2.70, 3.45, 3.90, 4.50, 5.10, 5.55, 6.30, 7.65, 8.70, 9.75,
    11.40, 11.85, 12.45, 13.05, 14.10, 17.40, 18.45, 20.55, 22.80])
i01 = np.array([0.00, 2.77, 3.59, 3.80, 3.90, 3.96, 3.98, 4.03, 4.11, 4.18, 4.25, 
                4.35, 4.38, 4.42, 4.45, 4.52, 4.73, 4.79, 4.93, 5.07])
u02 = np.array([0.00, 1.05, 1.65, 2.85, 3.75, 4.80, 5.55, 6.30, 8.25, 9.75, 12.15, 13.05, 16.80])
i02 = np.array([0.00, 0.06, 1.83, 7.13, 9.02, 9.41, 9.54, 9.68, 9.99, 10.23, 10.61, 10.75, 11.35])

u03 = np.array([0.00, 0.96, 1.80, 3.12, 3.96, 4.92, 6.84, 7.68, 9.72, 10.44])
i03 = np.array([0.00, 0.15, 7.26, 15.25, 15.91, 16.28, 16.95, 17.24, 17.95, 18.20])

u04 = np.array([0.00, 0.60, 1.08, 1.44, 1.68, 2.28, 2.64, 3.48, 4.68, 6.36, 7.56])
i04 = np.array([0.00, 0.20, 2.20, 5.56, 8.42, 16.07, 18.93, 21.62, 22.45, 23.29, 23.88])

x_gyp = np.arange(6, 25.1, 0.1)
y_gyp = 200/x_gyp

x_nag = [0, 12]
y_nag = [40, 0]

u_vh = np.array([0,0.51,0.60,0.64,0.67,0.74,0.77,0.79,0.83,0.86,0.92])
i_vh = np.array([0,0,3.05,11.32,30,250.14,531.820,816.89,1629.97,2431.52,4430.13])

###
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [3, 1]})
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)

#axs[0][0].plot(u_vh, i_vh, 'C1' '-o')
axs[0][0].set_xlim([0, 1]);
axs[0][0].set_ylim([0, 50]);
axs[0][0].set_xticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1));
axs[0][0].set_yticks(np.arange(0, 6000, 1000));
axs[0][0].invert_xaxis()
axs[0][0].yaxis.tick_right()
axs[0][0].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
axs[0][0].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

axs[0][1].plot(u01, i01, 'C1' '-o', u02, i02, 'C2' '-x', u03, i03, 'C3' '-^', u04, i04, 'C4' '-s', x_gyp, y_gyp, x_nag, y_nag, 'C7')
axs[0][1].set_xlim([0, 27]);
axs[0][1].set_ylim([0, 50]);
axs[0][1].set_xticks(np.arange(0, 27, 1));
axs[0][1].set_yticks(np.arange(0, 51, 1));
axs[0][1].xaxis.tick_top()

axs[1][0].plot(i_vh, u_vh, 'C1' '-o')
axs[1][0].set_xlim([0, 1000]);
axs[1][0].set_ylim([0, 1]);
#axs[1][0].set_xticks(np.arange(0, 100, 10));
axs[1][0].set_yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1));
axs[1][0].invert_xaxis()
axs[1][0].invert_yaxis()
axs[1][0].xaxis.tick_top()
#axs[1][0].yaxis.tick_right()
axs[1][0].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

#axs[1][1].plot(u_vh, i_vh, 'C1' '-o')
axs[1][1].set_xlim([0, 27]);
axs[1][1].set_ylim([0, 1]);
axs[1][1].set_xticks(np.arange(0, 27, 1));
axs[1][1].set_yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1));
axs[1][1].invert_yaxis()

plt.figure(figsize=(3, 10));
```

I think the result would look better if ticklabels were placed inside the graph.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post a picture, so here are the links:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdEcI.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OyzC.png

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is "incorrect" in your generated output graph and what the expected changes would be.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.